# How to detect phone lock/unlock in android with KivyMD?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to make an application that needs to save some data when the user locked the phone, and then read it when the phone is unlocked, can `def on_pause` and `def on_resume` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **buildozer.spec** put:

> requirements = kivy==2.0.0, jnius, kivymd, android

> android.minapi = 21

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivymd.app import MDApp

if platform == 'android':
    from jnius import autoclass
    PowerManager = autoclass('android.os.PowerManager')
    Context = autoclass("android.content.Context")
    context = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity").mActivity

KV = """
Screen:
    MDLabel:
        id: label
        text: 'Screen states:'
        halign: 'center'
"""


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def check_is_phone_lock(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            try:
                powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)
                isScreenOn = powerManager.isInteractive()
                print(f'isScreenOn: {isScreenOn}')
                screen_state = 'Off' if isScreenOn is False else 'On'
                self.root.ids.label.text += f'\nscreen - {screen_state}'
                return screen_state
            except Exception as err:
                return str(err)

    def on_pause(self):
        self.check_is_phone_lock()
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        self.check_is_phone_lock()


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Comment: Mark as solution if it helped

Comment: Haven't tried it yet! Will do it when I try it